# Shopify PLUS - additional checkout custom field

Tags: shopify, liquid

I was trying to add additional custom field in the checkout screen and here is my code:

```
<div class="additional-checkout-fields" style="display:none">
  <div class="fieldset fieldset--address-type" data-additional-fields>
    <div class="field field--optional field--address-type">
      <h2 class="additional-field-title">ADDRESS TYPE</h2>
      <div class="field__input-wrapper">
        <label>
          <input data-backup="Residential" class="input-checkbox" aria-labelledby="error-for-address_type" type="checkbox" name="checkout[Residential]" id="checkout_attributes_Residential" value="Residential" /> 
          <span>Residential</span>
        </label>
        <label>
          <input data-backup="Commercial" class="input-checkbox" aria-labelledby="error-for-address_type" type="checkbox" name="checkout[Commercial]" id="checkout_attributes_Commercial" value="Commercial" /> 
          <span>Commercial</span> 
        </label>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  if (window.jQuery) {
    jquery = window.jQuery;
  } else if (window.Checkout && window.Checkout.$) {
   jquery = window.Checkout.$;
  }

  jquery(function() {
    if (jquery('.section--shipping-address .section__content').length) {
      var addType = jquery('.additional-checkout-fields').html();
      jquery('.section--shipping-address .section__content').append(addType);
    }
  });
</script>
```

It returns the checkout page like this -

[image: Checkout Custom Fields]

The problem is - once I click continue button and comes back to this page again, I don't see the checkbox checked. I feel the values are not being passed or may be something else.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the usecase, it looks like you want the user to select the Address Type either Residential or Commercial so a raido button group seems more suitable. I have edited the HTML to create the Radio Button instead of Checkbox. To maintain the state, I have used [Session Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). You may also replace Session Storage with [Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) if you want to do so. For explanation check code comments.

```
<div class="additional-checkout-fields" style="display:none">
   <div class="fieldset fieldset--address-type" data-additional-fields>
      <div class="field field--optional field--address-type">
         <h2 class="additional-field-title">ADDRESS TYPE</h2>
         <div class="field__input-wrapper">
            <label>
            <input class="input-radio" aria-label="" type="radio"  name="checkout[address_type]" id="checkout_attributes_Residential" value="residential" checked>
            <span>Residential</span>
            </label>
            <label>
            <input class="input-radio" aria-label="" type="radio"name="checkout[address_type]" id="checkout_attributes_Commercial" value="commercial">
            <span>Commercial</span>  
            </label>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript part

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >

    if (window.jQuery) {
        jquery = window.jQuery;
    } else if (window.Checkout && window.Checkout.$) {
    jquery = window.Checkout.$;
}

jquery(function() {
    if (jquery('.section--shipping-address .section__content').length) {
        var addType = jquery('.additional-checkout-fields').html();
        jquery('.section--shipping-address .section__content').append(addType);

        // Get saved data from sessionStorage
        let savedAddressType = sessionStorage.getItem('address_type');

        // if some value exist in sessionStorage
        if (savedAddressType !== null) {
            jquery('input[name="checkout[address_type]"][value=' + savedAddressType + ']').prop("checked", true);
        }

        // Listen to change event on radio button
        jquery('input[name="checkout[address_type]"]').change(function() {
            if (this.value !== savedAddressType) {
                savedAddressType = this.value;
                sessionStorage.setItem('address_type', savedAddressType);
            }

        });

    }
}); 

</script>
```

Comment: I used local storage as David suggested in an earlier answer. But your answer is more accurate hence I am accepting it! JazakaAllah khair!

Answer (score 1):

You are responsible for managing the state of your added elements. Shopify could care a less about stuff you add, so of course when you flip around between screens, it will be up to you to manage the contents. Use localStorage or a cookie. Works wonders. As a bonus exercise, ensure that your custom field values are assigned to the order when you finish a checkout. You might find all your hard work is for nothing as those value languish in la-la land unless you explicitly add them as order notes or attributes.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Do you have any documentation or link where I can see some working example?

Comment: No, but Shopify has plenty of documentation. Should take you little time to figure out what you can/cannot do with checkout.liquid and how to persist the values you may play with there. I think you are much better off doing this in the cart, as that is dead simple... compared to messing with checkout.

Comment: Cart is much easier but the customer needs it in checkout since some people might want to skip the cart.

I really appreciate your help but I don't think Shopify has such documentation available.

Comment: There are articles about messing with checkout.liquid. Not to mention, since you dove into it, you have the obligation to experiment and figure it out by yourself too. It does suck though that collecting that extra info in checkout is a tad more work than at the cart level. Wish I could help but nope.